# How to access current page elements in lightning?

Tags: lightning-experience, email-template, email2case

Is there a way to access the iframe where Email Body is filled in? I want our users to have their signature populated when they compose a new email or reply to a received email. I was able to do it for compose part with setting predefined values for Send Email **case.Action** but that is not working for Reply.

[image]

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_send_email_quick_action_considerations.htm&type=5) says only To, CC & BCC Recipients fields aren’t pre-filled for reply emails or forwarded emails. But doesn't say anything about HTML Body.

I see a option that says Insert Paragraph Here when i hover over the Email Body like below

[image]

It will be a great change if i could implement something similar to Insert Signature.

Now, i am left with only one option to access the iframe and add signature to the body when clicked on Reply

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321267&type=1&mode=1). To summarize, assuming you aren't using an HTML email template, users can add a signature individually by clicking your user icon > click 'Email' > click 'My Email Settings' and entering their signature in the email signature field.

If you are instead using an email template, you can define merge fields for the signature on the template itself. Here is [documentation on how to do that](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_create_a_template.htm&type=5).

Comment: thank you for the response. Some of our users have more than one signatures and want to choose depending on the email they are sending. We had a custom object with rich text area fields where users could store signatures and then there's a JS button on case which hacks the Email Body iframe and adds signature inside by querying the rich text area fields.